# RTL Text in Nativescript

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I use Persian text in my app which is a Right-to-left language like Arabic.
I want to change my text direction from LTR(default) to RTL but it seems there is no option to do it. I used `direction: rtl` in my style but it doesn't work. I set `text-align: right` and it is ok for text with only one line, but when my text is more than one line and I use `textWrap="true"` in my Label so it doesn't work.

This is my code:

```
<StackLayout>
    <Label horizontalAlignment="right"
        text="اگر می خواهید رتبه فروشگاه ووکامرس خود را در صفحات نتایج موتورهای جستجو (SERPs) ارتقا دهید، تمرکز بر روی سئو امری ضروری است. برای بسیاری از افراد سئو بخشی پایانی طراحی است، اما کار بهتر پیش خواهد ..."
        class="news-main__content" textWrap="true"></Label>
</StackLayout>
```

result:
[image]

**Update:**

Finally, I found the solution myself to do that. Just use `WebView` component and insert `text-direction: rtl` inside of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NativeScript doesn't provide RTL support out of the box, yet. However, there is a plugin that provides this capability on Layout level. It can be set as a property of the layout or via CSS. The plugin can be found in the [NativeScript Marketplace](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/@nativescript-rtl%2Fui). Not sure if it will handle the text direction, though. But if not - you can give the author a hand and implement it together.

Comment: I think at the least Label by default supports RTL, as far I tried when the language is RTL the label is aligned to right by default. Try removing `horizontalAlignment` and `news-main__content`, may be some of your style is preventing it from being right aligned.

Comment: What you said was not what I was looking for. anyway thank you, I got sure there is no way to do that.

Comment: @Manoj As I said, One line text in Label becomes RTL correctly but in more than one line, it doesn't show correctly and that is my issue. in the other word, when I use multiple texts and have to use `textWrap`, It shows LTR, not RTL.

Comment: I double checked again, it works just fine with multi line Label too.